# My Streamlit app crashes when multiple users attempt to use the app at the same time

Tags: python, deployment, cloud, streamlit

I have built this multifunctional Streamlit app that pulls data from a database and does some computations then outputs multiple calculated variables on the Streamlit app. The app works perfectly on my local environment and when deployed, it works fine for a single user.

The moment a second user attempts to use the app in production, the whole app crashes and does not provide adequate information on what could be responsible. It's a 3-page app with each page showing a different modules. Find below my code for the main page:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
from PIL import Image
import datetime as dt

st.set_page_config(page_title= 'Enrollee Utilization',layout='wide', initial_sidebar_state='expanded')


locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
image = Image.open('avonwhite.png')
st.image(image, use_column_width=False)

st.sidebar.title('Navigation')
options = st.sidebar.radio('Module', options=['Home Page', 'Enrollee Utilization Summary', 'Enrollee Plan Benefit Limit'])

query = 'SELECT PolicyNo\
        ,ClientName\
        ,[Policy Inception]\
        ,[Policy Expiry]\
        ,PlanType\
        ,MemberType\
        ,MemberNo\
        ,Name\
        ,Gender\
        ,DATEDIFF(year,DOB,getdate()) MemberAge\
        ,State\
        ,PrimaryProviderName\
        ,Email\
        ,MobileNo\
         from [dbo].[tbl_MemberMasterView]'

query1 = 'SELECT * from vw_utilization_data'



@st.cache_data(ttl = dt.timedelta(hours=24))
def get_data_from_sql():
    conn = pyodbc.connect(
    'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='
    +st.secrets['server']
    +';DATABASE='
    +st.secrets['database']
    +';UID='
    +st.secrets['username']
    +';PWD='
    +st.secrets['password']
    )
    active_enrolees = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
    utilization_data = pd.read_sql(query1, conn)
    utilization_data['EncounterDate'] = pd.to_datetime(utilization_data['EncounterDate'])
    conn.close()
    return active_enrolees, utilization_data

active_enrollees, utilization_data = get_data_from_sql()


limit_df = pd.read_csv('Benefit_Limits.csv')

st.session_state['utilization_data'] = utilization_data

memberid = st.sidebar.text_input('Enrollee Member ID')
st.sidebar.button(label='Submit')

if 'id' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['id'] = None

if memberid is not None:
    st.session_state['id'] = memberid

def display_member_utilization(id):
    if not id.isdigit():
        st.write('Enter a valid integer for MemberNo')
        return

    id = int(id)

    if id not in active_enrollees['MemberNo'].values:
        st.write('No data found for the given member number')
        return

    policy_start_date = pd.to_datetime(active_enrollees.loc[active_enrollees['MemberNo'] == id, 'Policy Inception'].iat[0])
    policy_end_date = pd.to_datetime(active_enrollees.loc[active_enrollees['MemberNo'] == id, 'Policy Expiry'].iat[0])

    member_pa_value = utilization_data.loc[
        (utilization_data['MemberNo'] == id) &
        (utilization_data['EncounterDate'] >= policy_start_date) &
        (utilization_data['EncounterDate'] <= policy_end_date),
        'ApprovedPAAmount'].sum()        
    member_pa_value = '#' + locale.format_string('%d', member_pa_value, grouping=True)
    membername = active_enrollees.loc[active_enrollees['MemberNo'] == id, 'Name'].iat[0]
    client = active_enrollees.loc[active_enrollees['MemberNo'] == id, 'ClientName'].iat[0]
    plan = active_enrollees.loc[active_enrollees['MemberNo'] == id, 'PlanType'].iat[0]
    membertype = active_enrollees.loc[active_enrollees['MemberNo'] == id, 'MemberType'].iat[0]
    memberage = active_enrollees.loc[active_enrollees['MemberNo'] == id, 'MemberAge'].iat[0]
    member_utilization = utilization_data.loc[
        (utilization_data['EncounterDate'] >= policy_start_date) &
        (utilization_data['EncounterDate'] <= policy_end_date) &
        (utilization_data['MemberNo'] == id),
        ['AvonPACode','Hospital', 'EncounterDate', 'Benefits', 'Speciality', 'ServiceDescription', 'ApprovedPAAmount' ]
    ].set_index('AvonPACode')

    if membername is not None and options == 'Home Page':  
    
        st.metric(label = 'Enrollee Name', value = membername)
        st.metric(label = 'Enrollee Client', value = client)
        st.metric(label = 'Enrollee Plan', value = plan)
        st.metric(label = 'Total Utilization Within Current Policy', value=member_pa_value)

        col3, col4 = st.columns(2)
        col3.metric(label = 'Enrollee Age', value = memberage)
        col4.metric(label = 'Member Type', value = membertype)

        col5, col6 = st.columns(2)        
        col5.metric(label = 'Policy Inception', value = str(policy_start_date))
        col6.metric(label = 'PolicyExpiry', value = str(policy_end_date))
    

    elif len(member_utilization) > 0 and options == 'Enrollee Utilization Summary':
        st.subheader('Utilization summary for ' + membername)
        utilization_summary = member_utilization.groupby('Benefits')['ApprovedPAAmount'].sum().__round__(2)
        st.dataframe(utilization_summary, use_container_width=True)
        st.subheader('Utilization details for '+ membername)
        st.dataframe(member_utilization,use_container_width=True)
    elif options == 'Enrollee Plan Benefit Limit':
        enrollee_benefit_limit = limit_df.loc[
            (limit_df['ClientName'] == client) &
            (limit_df['ClassName'] == plan)
        ]
        null_cols = enrollee_benefit_limit.columns[enrollee_benefit_limit.isnull().all()]
        enrollee_benefit_limit.drop(null_cols, axis = 1, inplace = True)
        enrollee_benefit_limit = enrollee_benefit_limit.iloc[:, 6:].reset_index(drop=True)
        enrollee_benefit_limit = enrollee_benefit_limit.to_dict('index')
    
        st.write(enrollee_benefit_limit)
        return`
```

I have used caching to only run new data from the database every 24hours and also used session_state to keep each ID inputted by different sessions. How can I debug my code to see if there's something I'm missing or this is just due to the resource limit on Streamlit cloud? The error I'm getting is not explicit enough, so I'm feeling there's a problem with my implementation.

[this is the page displayed when the app crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haSuz.png)

Comment: could you please share the application logs when it crashes and also the CPU usage? the errors

Comment: The memory usage for the website is between 50-60mb when I checked. I also noticed that I was able to access the webpage on my laptop using different browsers and I was able to use the site on both browsers without the app crashing. However, the moment I shared the link with someone to try using it from another PC, it crashes again. This is very strange and I cannot identify why this is happening.

Comment: @Doracahl I have added the page displayed when the page crashes to my previous post. Please let me know if you require any additional info to help me troubleshoot this. Thank you for your help.